# what kind of widget is useful in this?

Tags: qt

I need to have a list of items as like this..

[image: sample designa created with qt designer]

in this when deletePushButton is clicked the entire row should be deleted.

since this list is dynamically created, I am creating number of horizandal layout's and adding to a vertical layout in code, my problem is how to map the 3 items which is in horizandal layout. and I am not sure what is the better approach for this design.

I am using Qt 4.8.1 in Win 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new widget and place your three controls onto it.

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QLabel *label;
    QLineEdit *edit;
    QPushButton *deleteButton;
};

MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
   QWidget(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel("text");
    edit = new QLineEdit;
    deleteButton = new QPushButton;

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(label);
    mainLayout->addWidget(edit);
    mainLayout->addWidget(deleteButton);

    setLayout(mainLayout);

    connect(deleteButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
}
```